# spring bootをgradleでビルドしたjarファイルについて

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat, gradle, jar

どなたか、お詳しい方教えて頂けますでしょうか。

現在、spring bootでwebアプリケーションを作成しております。
gradleのビルドで、Tomcatを内包するfat jar（uber jar）を作成し、
Jdk8で起動させていますが、apacheの「htaccess」にあたるファイルは存在するのでしょうか。

htaccessの内容を編集し、存在しないURLへの制御したいと思っております。
よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apacheの`.htaccess`に当たるTomcatの設定は`web.xml`の`<security-constraint>`になります（※）。日本語であれば、[このページ](https://www.techscore.com/tech/Java/JavaEE/Servlet/10-3/)が分かりやすいと思います。

Spring Bootでも`web.xml`は使えるので、このあたりが参考になるのではないかと思います。

- [Stackoverflow - Spring Boot with container security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064999/spring-boot-with-container-security/37067552)
- [Stackoverflow - Use web.xml security constraints with Spring Boot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42285665/use-web-xml-security-constraints-with-spring-boot)

※.htaccessと完全に同じ機能ではないので、要件を満たせるかどうかは分かりませんが。

**追記：** 「存在しないURLへの制御をしたい」ということであれば、`web.xml`の`<error-page>`の設定を変えた方がいいのかもしれません。

- [Stackoverflow - Redirecting a 404 error page to a custom page of my Spring MVC webapp in Tomcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18780257/redirecting-a-404-error-page-to-a-custom-page-of-my-spring-mvc-webapp-in-tomcat)